# How to implement Recaptcha in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, recaptcha, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm having a problem when navigating to a new URL using router.push("/dashboard") or using NuxtLink, because later on the dashboard page the Google recaptcha doesn't load, so I need to refresh the page for it to work. So, can anyone help me how to implement recaptcha in Nuxt 3? I tried, but it doesn't work properly.

Below is the code for how I imported the recaptcha script into nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  alias: {
    css: "/<rootDir>/assets/css",
  },
   app: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || "/",

    head: {
      script: [
        { src: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js', async: true, defer: true } //importando o recaptcha
      ],
    }
  }, 

  css: ['@/assets/css/main.css'], 
  
});
```

The code now on the Dashboard page where I place the recaptcha:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LedcrYoAAAAAKcf9pvM5x11DXBi1Ik5oke8qQ0v"></div> <!-- recaptcha -->
        <NuxtLink to="/painel">Voltar para o Painel</NuxtLink><br>
        <!-- <a href="/painel">Voltar Painel</a> -->
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I tested your implementation and it's working on my end, here is the screenshot https://ibb.co/4TG6drc. If you could provide a minimalist example on stackblitz that would be helpful.

Comment: Did you navegate between routes to see if recaptcha load?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-render the recaptcha like this.

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
    'sitekey': ''
  })
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="html_element"></div>
    <NuxtLink to="/local">Local</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Tested it and it works, see screen-recording
https://staging.streamable.com/4w7f4r